# Working with Cyrillic strings

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

For example, I have cyrilic type word: "Кириллица"

How can I work with it in PowerShell script? I want use this string in `drawString` function.

I'm getting some abnormal chars...

Code:

```
$swp_curr_dir = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
[void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")

Function AddTextToImage {
    # Orignal code from http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/?p=1012
    [CmdletBinding()]
    PARAM (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $sourcePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $destPath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String] $Title
    )

    Write-Verbose "Load System.Drawing"
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

    Write-Verbose "Get the image from $sourcePath"
    $srcImg = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($sourcePath)

    Write-Verbose "Create a bitmap as $destPath"
    $outputIImg = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap([int]($srcImg.width)),([int]($srcImg.height))

    Write-Verbose "Intialize Graphics"
    $Image = [System.Drawing.Graphics]::FromImage($outputIImg)
    $Image.SmoothingMode = "AntiAlias"

    $img_rectangle = New-Object Drawing.Rectangle 0, 0, $srcImg.Width, $srcImg.Height
    $Image.DrawImage($srcImg, $img_rectangle, 0, 0, $srcImg.Width, $srcImg.Height, ([Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel))

    Write-Verbose "Draw title: $Title"
    $Font = new-object System.Drawing.Font("SansSerif", 200, "Bold","Pixel")

    $rect = [System.Drawing.RectangleF]::FromLTRB(0, 0, $srcImg.Width, $srcImg.Height)
    $format = [System.Drawing.StringFormat]::GenericDefault
    $format.Alignment = [System.Drawing.StringAlignment]::Center
    $format.LineAlignment = [System.Drawing.StringAlignment]::Center

    #styling font
    $Brush = New-Object Drawing.SolidBrush([System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255))

    #lets draw outline
    $path = New-Object System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath
    $path.AddString($Title, $Font.FontFamily, $Font.Style, $Font.Size, $rect, $format)
    $Image.DrawPath([System.Drawing.Pens]::Black, $path)

    #lets draw font
    $Image.DrawString($Title, $Font, $Brush, $rect, $format)

    Write-Verbose "Save and close the files"
    $outputIImg.save($destPath, [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::jpeg)
    $outputIImg.Dispose()
    $srcImg.Dispose()
}

AddTextToImage -sourcePath ($swp_curr_dir + "\image.jpg") -destPath ($swp_curr_dir + "\output.jpg") -Title "Кириллица"

cmd /c pause
```

In this code, I'm trying output new image with drawed cyrilic string on them.

in beginning, is available image.jpg in the same directory where is our powershell script. Im just running this script via right mouse click. After executing the code, is appearing new additional image with centered text on it. Text is not in readable format.

1. Original image link: https://i.imgsafe.org/b2ff1cb235.jpg
2. Output
   image link: https://i.imgsafe.org/b2ff23d8f9.jpg

Solution: Scrip.ps1 if was saved in utf-8 encoding format, it must include BOM.

Right answer from user https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral

Comment: Can you show us the code and the resulting graphics?

Comment: Show how results look for you. What is script file encoding? If you do `echo 'Название картинки'` in script file, does it print text on console correctly?

Comment: If you save script file in UTF-8 encoding, then it should include BOM for UTF-8 to be properly recognized.

Comment: Yes, it solved problem.. Why its happening like this?

Comment: Why what? Powershell requires BOM in UTF8-encoded scripts. That's how it works. Apparently, because it was developed on Windows where UTF-8 isn't system default encoding.

Comment: Most editors on Windows will also just save in UTF-16LE when the text contains non-Latin characters, which will also work out of the box for PowerShell.